# Run a maintenance task on all Jenkins nodes

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-job-dsl

I have a Jenkins setup with dynamic nodes from a cloud. I need to run a specific maintenance task on all the nodes. I know I can discover all the nodes with

```
def nodeNames(label) {
    def nodes = []
    jenkins.model.Jenkins.instance.computers.each { c ->
        if (c.node.labelString.contains(label)) {
            nodes.add(c.node.selfLabel.name)
        }
    }   
    return nodes
}
```

But my concern is how do I run force to run it on all nodes. I tried to use the 'matrix' but it does not support dynamic values for the axes.
My preference would be to use a declarative pipeline but I'm okay to use scripted as well.